# Undo a git svn rebase

Tags: git

Is there anyway to undo a git svn rebase?

I incorrectly did some merges and want to just go back to the way things were before I tried to rebase from the central repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) to find the hash that described the state of your tree before the rebase and then check it out.